# How to update package.json dependencies when linking from globally installed packages?

Tags: npm, dependencies, package.json

I organize my development projects installing globally all the npm packages I need with:

```
npm -g install [package]
```

Then I simlink individually the dependencies I need for each project with:

```
npm link [package]
```

This way, I have to update manually each package.json file to add the dependency, and when I upgrade the global node_modules I have to go and update all the package.json projects.

For this first issue I tried `npm link [package] --save` but it doesn't add the dependency to package.json and if I use `npm install [package] --save` it installs the package locally, thing I don't want.

Is there any way to be able to not have to configure package.json manually and be able to have an updated configuration of package.json from many different projects in a easier way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can install npm-check-updates, you can find the install and guide here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates

when running 'ncu' on the command-line in your root-folder where your package.json is, it will list the packages that can be updated and by running 'ncu -u' on the command-line it updates all the packages for you.

Comment: It almost matches what I was looking for but I am looking for updating the global packages, not the local, and then update the certain local project `package.json`.

`Ncu` cannot upgrade global packages, as it states by itself. Indeed, it works for updating the `package.json` locally.